# JavaScript array of objects broken out into PHP arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

After several hours of Picasso coding (*my term*), I am stuck on how to efficiently convert this JavaScript array of objects into PHP (sent via AJAX).

In JavaScript, the array of objects looks like this after JSON encoding:

```
[
    {"pid":"282","seller_id":"3","qty":"5"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"1234","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"2345","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"3456","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"111","sn":"987","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"}
]
```

There are two data groupings - note that the first transfer lacks a serial number and is to an external vendor, making it a sale. The next 4 are all to "myself" (user is seller_id: 2), so these are internal transfers of product.

Anyway, the two types must be handled differently, so it would be immensely helpful if they were in separate arrays.

Therefore, I wish to end up with two PHP arrays:

```
arrSale[0] = "pid":"282","seller_id":"3","qty":"5"
```

and

```
arrXfer[0] = "pid":"284","sn":"1234","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"
arrXfer[1] = "pid":"284","sn":"2345","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"
arrXfer[2] = "pid":"284","sn":"3456","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"
arrXfer[3] = "pid":"111","sn":"987","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"
```

I know that I must use `$arrPHP = json_decode(jsonItems);` to decode the JSON, but what happens to the objects? How would I break them into the two groups? I can't even find website resources that discuss this.

Comment: loop over the array in either language and check if a row has `sn` property or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$JSON = '[
    {"pid":"282","seller_id":"3","qty":"5"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"1234","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"2345","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"284","sn":"3456","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"},
    {"pid":"111","sn":"987","seller_id":2,"qty":"1"}
]';

$array = json_decode($JSON);

$arrSale = $arrXfer = array();

foreach($array as $obj)
    if(isset($obj->sn)) $arrXfer[] = (array)$obj;
        else $arrSale[] = (array)$obj;

print_r($arrSale);
print_r($arrXfer);
```

It gives us:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array([pid] => 282[seller_id] => 3[qty] => 5)
)

Array(
    [0] => Array([pid] => 284[sn] => 1234[seller_id] => 2[qty] => 1)
    [1] => Array([pid] => 284[sn] => 2345[seller_id] => 2[qty] => 1)  
    [2] => Array([pid] => 284[sn] => 3456[seller_id] => 2[qty] => 1)  
    [3] => Array([pid] => 111[sn] => 987[seller_id] => 2[qty] => 1)  
)
```

Comment: I don't mind! Take good care of it, please! It likes cream cheese

Comment: I'm usually a procedural guy, but getting some odd results which might have to do with the PHP ver on my host?  Got error `syntax error, unexpected "[" on line 2`, but it worked after change to `$arrSale = $arrXfer = array();` That is just a poss symptom. Prob is here: At end of code block, I put: `$xcnt = count($arrXfer); $scnt = count($arrSale);` and echoed result, but both were zero..?  (Used same data as above)

Comment: That's because of your PHP version. Square brackets array notation added at version `5.4`, before that only `array(...)` worked.

Comment: Zero? Do `var_dump($array)` after the `json_decode(..)` to see if the data is there, there maybe some JSON error or something?

Comment: Yeah, you're right Oleg, I think you've given me the answer. I just have to work out how to make it work for me.  Thanks tons... and enjoy your awesome brain.

Comment: To send things back to AJAX the best way would be to print it in JSON format, as it's native to JavaScript. Like `echo json_encode($arrSale);`

Comment: I must return again to thank you, Oleg. Yesterday I was soooo stuck -- I couldn't have thought my way through a paint-by-numbers (probably looming-of-deadline angst.)  You set me back in the saddle, and demo'd some helpful new tricks to boot, and I wish you [godspeed in your endeavors](http://is.gd/bethlehem11).